# Is it possible to claim Bitcoin Cash from an exchange that does not support it by broadcasting BTC transaction in BCH network?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

Is it possible to claim BCH without knowing private key?

I have some Bitcoins in CoinsBank account  (https://coinsbank.com) topped up before the fork. CoinsBank officially declared that they will never support BCH, so I'm seeking for ways to claim it.

For example, what if I create a BTC wallet, send my bitcoins there, and then broadcast the same transaction in BCH network?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't claim BCH without knowing private key, even if you withdraw that Bitcoin to your BTC wallet. Because, it means that you will get Bitcoin into your wallet after BCH fork.

To claim BCH, you have to have Bitcoin on your wallet before BCH fork.

If you make a BTC transaction, it is not possible to broadcast the same transaction in BCH network manually. BCH uses "sighash_forkid" to distinguish, so BCH won't accept the transaction that you made and broadcasted to BTC network.

Comment: I understand that it won't happen by default. But in order to send BTC to my wallet CoinsBank has to broadcast a transaction in BTC network. Is it possible to broadcast the same transaction in BCH network manually?

Comment: No. BCH uses "sighash_forkid" to distinguish, so BCH won't accept the transaction that you made and broadcasted to BTC network.